# add / remove a class inside previous or next parent

Tags: javascript

```
<div class='part'>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
</div>

<div class='part'>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
</div>

<div class='part'>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    total = $('.postitle').length;
    if (e.keyCode == 38 && $('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked') && $('.pmarked').index() > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        listup();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 40 && $('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked') && $('.pmarked').index() <= total-2) {
        e.preventDefault();
        listdown();
    }
});

function listup(){
    var prev = $('.pmarked').prevAll('.postitle:first');
    $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
    prev.addClass('pmarked');
}

function listdown(){
    var next = $('.pmarked').nextAll('.postitle:first');
    $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
    next.addClass('pmarked');
}
```

So I want to add/remove `.pmarked` class to `.postitle` (not to `.title`) by pressing `arrow-up` and `arrow-down` on keyboard.

The above code works fine but only if `prev/next` item is inside the same `.part` div.

How to jump on previous or next `.part` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,the way you select the element have to change

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  let index = $('.postitle').toArray().indexOf($('.pmarked')[0]);
  total = $('.postitle').length;
  if (e.keyCode == 38 && $('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked') && $('.pmarked').index() > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    listup(index - 1);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40 && $('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked') && $('.pmarked').index() <= total - 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
    listdown(index > total - 2 ? 0 : index + 1);
  }
});

function listup(index) {
  var prev = $('.postitle').eq(index);
  $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
  prev.addClass('pmarked');
}

function listdown(index) {
  var next = $('.postitle').eq(index);
  $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
  next.addClass('pmarked');
}
```

```css
.pmarked {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='part'>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
</div>

<div class='part'>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='postitle pmarked'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
</div>

<div class='part'>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
<div class='postitle'>323</div>
</div>
```

i got the present element index by

```
  let index = $('.postitle').toArray().indexOf($('.pmarked')[0]);
```

and calc the previous element index by `index-1` and next element index by `index > total - 2 ? 0 : index + 1`